# Show that G is not simple where $|G| = 2^2 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Show that if a group $G$ has order $|G|=2^2\cdot5^3\cdot7^9$, then $G$ is not simple.

$\textbf{Def:}$ A group $G$ is $\textbf{simple}$ if and only if $|G|>1$ and $\lbrace 1_G\rbrace$ as well as $G$ are its only normal subgroups.

I tried to use contradiction. First assuming that $G$ is simple. I was under the impression that we have to do this proof by cases with Sylow subgroups $n_2$, $n_5$, and $n_7$. I am stuck here since I thought we have to think about case 1 where $n_2 \equiv 1(\bmod2)$ and $n_2|5^3\cdot7^9 $. The trouble I'm having is wouldn't there be many factors where this case is true? Similarly for the other 2 Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Okay, assume G is simple.  What does this mean, by definition (of a simple group)? (Please add that to your post, if you plan to do a proof by contradiction).  Then:  Do you have any information given the order of the group that might contradict this?

Comment: Where did you get $\bmod 13$?

Comment: $n_7\equiv 1\text{ (mod 7)}$ and $n_7\big|2^2\cdot5^3$ but $1\not\equiv_7 2,4,5,25,125,10,250,20,100,500\implies n_7\in\{1,50\}$ could this help you?

Comment: @ChrisCuster thank you. I have several problems in front of me and was looking at the wrong modulo. I have fixed this in the edit.

Comment: @Vajra yes that does help. So you just have to use logic on which numbers will work and break it down that way? Should there not be that many factors for the other cases as well?

Comment: @amWhy I have added the definition. To contradict the fact that G is simple, we can find a normal subgroup with order not equal to 1

Comment: Unless I made a mistake @Vajra's calculation leads to the conclusion that $G$ must have $50$ Sylow $7$-subgroups with pairwise trivial intersections. For if $Q=P_1\cap P_2$ is the largest non-trivial intersection then, by the properties of $p$-groups, $Q$ has a non-trivial normalizer in both $P_1$ and $P_2$. This implies that $N=N_G(Q)$ has more than one Sylow $7$ properly containing $Q$. Hence it, too must have $50$ Sylow $7$-subgroups. By maximality of $Q$, the Sylow-$7$s of $N$ must be contained in distinct Sylows of $G$. Hence $Q$ is contained in all the Sylow $7$s and is normal in $G$.

Comment: Or, I guess, if $G$ has exactly $50$ Sylow $7$'s, then $G$ embeds into $S_{50}$. Then it suffices to show that the order of $S_{50}$ is not divisible by $7^9$...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen True, but I think the argument that $7^9$ does not divide $|S_{50}|$ is easier.

Comment: By God, @Marktmeister. That works! I thought $50$ is too big for that argument to work, but it is just right. $7^8$ is the highest power that is a factor of $50!$. I predict that in a few weeks time there will be undergrads working this out :-)

Comment: Indeed, @DerekHolt. Particularly given that my line of attack had yet to reach a contradiction :-) Anyway, surely the large Sylow $7$s are the most peculiar property of this group.

Comment: Does this mean that $n_2=1$ and $n_5=1$ because $n_2$ divides 4 and $n_5$ divides 125?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen May I ask why "the Sylow-7s of N must be contained in 'distinct' Sylows of G"? What if 2 of them are contained in the same Sylow of G?

Comment: @Michael Then those two Sylows of $G$ would have an intersection larger than $Q$, contradicting the choice of $Q$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry but I can't see why the intersection would be larger than Q.

Comment: @Michael $N_{P_1}(Q)$ is strictly larger than $Q$. Hence the Sylows of $N$ are strictly larger than $Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the intended solution is the argument in the comments using $n_7 = 50$, but it's worth knowing that we can completely avoid thinking about $n_7$. In fact we have the following.

> **Proposition:** The order of a finite simple group $G$ is divisible by either $8$ or $12$ (assuming [Feit-Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem)), or the smallest prime $p$ dividing the order is odd and divides it with multiplicity at least $3$ (not assuming Feit-Thompson, but Feit-Thompson implies this never happens).

*Proof.* By the [Burnside normal $p$-complement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_p-complement), if a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ is normal in its centralizer $N(P)$, then it has a normal complement (a subgroup splitting the short exact sequence $1 \to P \to G \to G/P \to 1$), and in particular $G$ is not simple. Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ and write $\nu_p(G)$ for the exponent of $p$ dividing $|G|$. If $\nu_p(G) \le 2$ then the Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ is abelian (it must be either $C_p, C_p \times C_p$, or $C_{p^2}$) and the order of its automorphism group is only divisible by primes $\le p$, unless $p = 2$. We now split into cases:

- $p$ odd (by Feit-Thompson this never happens): since $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, the primes dividing $|N(P)|$ are all greater than $p$. It follows that $P$ is normal in $N(P)$ (since $N(P)/P$ can't act nontrivially on $P$), so $P$ has a normal complement. If $G$ is simple then this can't occur, so taking contrapositives, $\nu_p(G) \ge 3$.
- $p = 2$: $|\text{Aut}(P)|$ is only divisible by a prime $\ge 3$ when $P = C_2 \times C_2$, which has automorphism group $S_3$. If $G$ is simple then $P$ can't have a complement, so either $\nu_2(G) \ge 3$ or $P = C_2 \times C_2$ and the conjugation map $N(P)/P \to \text{Aut}(P)$ is surjective, which implies that $12 \mid |N(P)|$ and hence that $12 \mid |G|$. $\Box$